# Struts2 tags can't be found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, struts2, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm here to ask a question that others already asked but every answers I found don't fix my problem.

I'm currently using `struts2` with `maven` and `jetty-maven-plugin`, but eclipse is throwing errors about my `JSPs` files saying that it can't find the `/struts-tag.tld` file.

Also, when I launch the jetty:run command, it says:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M2:run (default-cli) on project starservice: Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M2:run failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M2:run: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext.getThreadContextMap()Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/spi/ReadOnlyThreadContextMap;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/9.3.0.M2/jetty-maven-plugin-9.3.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.1.1/sisu-inject-bean-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.9.4/sisu-guice-2.9.4-no_aop.jar
[...]
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.1/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

And the pom

```
<groupId>xx.xx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxxxx</artifactId>

<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1</version>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>starserv</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M2</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <war>${project.basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}.war</war>
                <webApp>
                    <webInfIncludeJarPattern>^$</webInfIncludeJarPattern>
                    <containerIncludeJarPattern>^$</containerIncludeJarPattern>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Because nothing's working.

Comment: Could you put your pom with your question?

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext.getThreadContextMap()Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/spi/ReadOnlyThreadContextMap;`

Comment: i've added it @asettouf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem.

You just need to add the log4j api to the same version of log4j in struts. For me it was

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In hope It will help someone!